# Entity Framework Core 1.1.2's DbSet implementation

Tags: dbset, entity-framework-core

I am writing a new database provider for Entity Framework Core 1.1.2 (with target framework: .NET 4.5.2), and I have a very frustrating issue. My relevant installed NuGet packages are:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

I have a MyDbSet class which inherits from Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet:

```
public class MyDbSet<TEntity> : DbSet<TEntity> where TEntity : class {
}
```

I have a context class which is as simple as:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext {
    public MyDbSet<MyOtherModel> Others { get; set; }

    // Constructor
    public MyModel() {
        others = new MyDbSet<MyOtherModel>();
    }
}
```

I instantiate a MyContext object,

```
MyContext myContext = new MyContext();
```

and I want to do the following:

```
myContext.Others.Add(new MyOtherModel());
```

**Here I receive an exception saying that the *Add* method is unimplemented.**

Seeing the EF Core documentations, DbSet really is an abstract class with abstract, unimplemented methods. Is it right? Should I really write my own DbSet implementation? Or is there a default implementation of it somewhere? If so, which assembly / NuGet package do I need to access this?

Comment: The standard implementation is in `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet<T>`. But why you ever need to implement your own `DbSet<T>`? It has nothing to do with database providers.

Comment: Though `MyDbSet<T>` only inherits from `DbSet<T>`, and does not add any new functionality to its superclass, for design reasons it is needed to use a `MyDbSet<T>` class. I emphasize that it is not more than general `DbSet<T>`. However, I fully agree with you in that `DbSet<T>` **should not** have anything to do with when one writes a database provider. But I have a test code (for my provider) with an own `DbContext` class (`MyDbContext`)  which has a `MyDbSet<T>`-type property. When I try to add a new `T` object to this `DbSet<T>`, I get that the `Add` method is not implemented. Why?

Comment: Maybe only some dependencies are missing from my project, but I do not know which ones. Or something similar will be the root cause.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/release/2.2/src/EFCore/Internal/InternalDbSet.cs